# How to solve these 2 errors in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

This code is giving me a warning in 7 line which is

> "Warning 10: this expression should have type unit."

and giving me a error in line 8 which is

> "Error: This expression has type int -> int but an expression was expected of type 'a ref".

Someone help me solving this.

```
let rec schroder n = 
  let n = read_int () in
  let pointer = ref 0 in 
  for i = 1 to n-2 do
    pointer := !pointer + (schroder i * schroder n-i-1)
  done;
  schroder n = (3 * schroder n-1) + (!pointer);
  !schroder n
```

Comment: Function application takes precedence over binary operations. I suspect `schroder n-1` should instead be `schroder (n-1)` and `schroder n-i-1` should instead be `schroder (n-i-1)`.

Comment: And probably you want to replace the last `;` by `;;` and remove the `!` on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence rules of OCaml are sometimes different from other programming languages, so you should keep the [following table](https://ocaml.org/manual/expr.html#ss:precedence-and-associativity) close, when coding in OCaml.

For example,

```
foo x+1
```

Is actually understood by the OCaml parser as,

```
(foo x) + 1
```

It is because the function application operation (which is just a juxtaposition of two words together, e.g., `foo x`) has higher precedence than the infix operators. Therefore, if you want the arithmetic operator to be applied before the function application you have to use parentheses,

```
foo (x + 1)
```

Which actually makes the application look very similar to conventional languages such as C or Java(script).

The prefix symbols, such as `!` or `~`, contrary to the infix, have a higher precedence than the function application, so

```
!foo x
```

means `(!foo) x` not `!(foo x)`.

Finally, the expression `schroder n = (3 * schroder n-1) + (!pointer);` means, compare the result of `shroder n` (which is the application of the function `schroder` to `n` with the result of the expression `(3 * schroder n-1) + (!pointer)`. As with any other comparison, it will evaluate to a value of the boolean type, and the `;` operator yields a warning when it terminates a non-unit value, i.e., when you ignore a result of a computation that has a non-trivial value. Honestly, I am not sure what you were trying to achieve here, but keep in mind that `=` is a comparison operator that returns `true` if both sides are structurally equal. It is not an assignment operator, like in C. For the assignments you shall use `:=`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. TL; DR, here is the correct version:

```
let rec schroder n =
  if n = 0 then 1
  else if n = 1 then 2
  else begin
    let s = ref 0 in
    for k = 1 to n - 2 do
      s := !s + schroder k * schroder (n-k-1)
    done;
    !s + 3 * schroder (n-1)
  end
```

Let's walk step-by-step how to correct your code to reach this working version (assuming what you meant to have is a function that produces the Schröder numbers, which seems to be the case).

#### `n` is a parameter

When you write something like `let rec schroder n = ...`, you are defining a function `schroder` that takes one argument, `n`. There is no need to, then, `read_int ()`, since you already take an argument. Currently, your function simply ignores its argument. It's arguably better to have a function that takes a parameter, and then call it with `schroder (read_int ())` if you need to.
So your code becomes

```
let rec schroder n = 
  let pointer = ref 0 in 
  for i = 1 to n-2 do
    pointer := !pointer + (schroder i * schroder n-i-1)
  done;
  schroder n = (3 * schroder n-1) + (!pointer);
  !schroder n
```

#### Renaming variables

This is more of a personal adjustment, but naming a reference `pointer` is not that useful, because a reference is always (implicitly) a pointer, but it does not tell you the variable's purpose. Also, since you are doing a loop just to sum over generated elements of a sequence, which is a pretty standard thing to do (although it's not the most idiomatic thing to do in Caml), there is no need for this variable to have an long name. It's purpose is quite clear from the rest of the code. Let's just call it `s`, like `sum`, which is short and to the point. Calling it `acc` would have arguably also worked, for instance.

```
let rec schroder n = 
  let s = ref 0 in 
  for i = 1 to n-2 do
    s := !s + (schroder i * schroder n-i-1)
  done;
  schroder n = (3 * schroder n-1) + (!s);
  !schroder n
```

#### Working priorities out

Let's be explicit, and write (almost) **every** parenthesis, just to straighten the order of the operations:

```
let rec schroder n = 
  let s = ref 0 in 
  for i = 1 to n-2 do
    s := !s + ((schroder i) * (schroder (n-i-1)))
  done;
  schroder n = (3 * (schroder (n-1))) + (!s);
  !schroder n
```

Now, turns out `*` has already a higher priority than `+`, meaning `a + b * c` is the same as `a + (b * c)`. We can therefore remove these parenthesis.
Also, binary operations always have lower priority than unary operations, so `!b + c` is the same as `(!b) + c`. Finally, function application has the highest priority among binary operations, so `a b + c` is the same as `(a b) + c`. We can remove more parenthesis. In the end, we get

```
let rec schroder n = 
  let s = ref 0 in 
  for i = 1 to n-2 do
    s := !s + schroder i * schroder (n-i-1)
  done;
  schroder n = 3 * schroder (n-1)) + !s;
  !schroder n
```

This is understood by the compiler exactly as the previous program. However, this does not mean that, just because we striped out all the parenthesis we could, this code is better or more readable. This is also subjective, meaning if you are used to Caml operator priorities, code is more readable without parenthesis (if it's simple enough, like in this case), but if you are not then it's much better to have parenthesis. A good rule of thumb is: if you have a doubt, then put the parenthesis. Then look it up. But keep the parenthesis, so people who are going to read this (including you in the future) won't have to look it up to understand you. Also, this way you're sure of not screwing up.

Also, I did **not** parenthesize `!schroder n` because there is, as we will see in the next section, no way to parenthesize this for it to make sense.

#### Removing non-Caml syntax

I guess, what you meant by the lines

```
schroder n = 3 * schroder (n-1)) + !s;
!schroder n
```

was "I want `schroder n` to have the value `3 * schroder (n-1)) + !s`, so I make that assignment, then I return the value stored in `schroder n` with `!schroder n`".

Well, this is just not how Caml work (however, I think there are languages out there that work this way). First of all, the body of the function is meant to have the value of the call of the function with a parameter. This means that you don't need to assign that value *again*. Your function definition was *already* the assignment for the value of `schroder n`. So you can simply remove the "assigning" line. Also, Caml gave you a warning about that line because it did not understand it as an assignment, but simply as a boolean value (is `schroder n` equal to `3 * schroder (n-1)) + !s`?), which is then discarded. The compiler warns when you discard a value that is not `()` without using it, because it's likely an error.

So the code becomes

```
let rec schroder n = 
  let s = ref 0 in 
  for i = 1 to n-2 do
    s := !s + schroder i * schroder (n-i-1)
  done;
  !schroder n
```

Now, the syntax `!something` means `something` is of the form `ref value`, and `!something` is then equal to `value`. That is, `!` is the dereference operation. Of course, `schroder` is not a reference (it's a function), so it does not make sense to dereference it. For the same reason, because `schroder n` should be a number, it does not make sense to dereference it, so even `!(schroder n)` makes no sense. Let's remove that altogether.

What you actually want simply to return `!s + 3 * schroder (n-1)`, so let's do that.

```
let rec schroder n = 
  let s = ref 0 in 
  for i = 1 to n-2 do
    s := !s + schroder i * schroder (n-i-1)
  done;
  !s + 3 * schroder (n-1)
```

#### Adding a base case

We're almost done. This code will now happily compile, and even run. The problem is that it will never *stop* running (or it will, but crashing). That's because there is no base case! You keep calling `schroder n` with a smaller value of `n` each time, but you don't tell when you have to stop calling `schroder`. Let's do that. The base case are: `schroder 0 = 1` and `schroder 1 = 2`. So, simply

```
let rec schroder n =
  if n = 0 then 1
  else if n = 1 then 2
  else begin
    let s = ref 0 in
    for k = 1 to n - 2 do
      s := !s + schroder k * schroder (n-k-1)
    done;
    !s + 3 * schroder (n-1)
  end
```

NB. `begin` and `end` are exactly the same as `(` and `)`, respectively. They are required because `if` statements have higher priority than `;`, that is, `if a then b else c; d` is understood as `(if a then b else c); d`, not as `if a then b else (c; d)`, which is why you have to add these parenthesis. For readability reasons, you don't write parenthesis, but `begin` and `end` instead, giving `if a then b else begin c; d end`.

#### More idiomatic code?

I earlier said this was probably not the *most* idiomatic code in Caml. Acutally, it's pretty ok. It's just not written in a very functional way, which is (arguably) more idiomatic. An alternative would be

```
let rec schroder n =
  if n = 0 then 1
  else if n = 1 then 2
  else
    let s = List.init (n-2) (fun x -> x + 1)
      |> List.map (fun k -> schroder k * schroder (n-k-1))
      |> List.fold_left (+) 0 in
    3 * schroder (n-1) + s
```

This way, there is no loop in our code. We start by initializing a list with the values `[1; 2; ...; n-2]`, then `map` each value `k` to `schroder k * schroder (n-k-1)` (meaning we get the list `[schroder 1 * schroder (n-1-1); schroder 2 * schroder (n-2-1); ...; schroder (n-2) * schroder (n-(n-2)-1)]`). Finally, we sum all the elements of this list together, and we get `s`, which has the same value than `!s` in the previous version, at the end of the loop.

This might be (slightly) more idiomatic, but it's less efficient, because we allocate an extra list just to fold it again. This could be avoided, at the cost of having a code a little more verbose.

```
let rec init_seq f from to_ () =
  if from > to_ then Seq.Nil
  else Seq.Cons (f from, init_seq f (from+1) to_)

let rec schroder n =
  if n = 0 then 1
  else if n = 1 then 2
  else begin
    let s = init_seq (fun k -> schroder k * schroder (n-k-1)) 1 (n-2)
      |> Seq.fold_left (+) 0 in
    s + 3 * schroder (n-1)
```

Here we use `Seq`, which is the same as a `List` but it's lazy, meaning each element of the sequence does not get stored beforehand, but instead is calculated on-the-fly (so no intermediate allocation). We need a little extra function as there is no (at least, I am not aware of a) `Seq.init` which would work as `List.init`.

You note that this code is either less efficient (for the version with `List`) or more verbose, which is why the version I would stick with is the one with the loop.

Comment: BlackBeans thanks for the help with the code and for being so explicit with the errors which helped me a lot!!!

Comment: Please refrain from providing complete code samples when answering a homework question. You're running the learning experience of the student. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @ivg I was not aware that there was such a strong position on homework question. I won't do that again.